# c3p0 is always calling commit even if data is coming from Ehcache

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, ehcache

I have a web service which makes readonly call(bunch of select queries) to get data from DB. But it makes call to the database for the first time only, after that, all entities involved are cached in hibernate second level cache using Ehcache. The problem is even if my request is not making any DB call to get data, the application is always making a commit call to the database which is effecting my response time of the web service.

My web service response time is 90ms, out of which the commit call is contributing 35ms(40%) all the time. The datasource is configured as spring bean with data source class com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource as shown below.

It is making a commit call to DB for every call to the web service which I can see it in the call graph taken from appdynamics. The cache hit ratio is 100% for all those entries involved in the request.

[image]

```
<bean id="catalogReadDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <!-- jdbc properties -->
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!-- c3P0 properties -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${c3p0.acquireIncrement}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${c3p0.maxStatements}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTime}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${c3p0.preferredTestQuery}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin}" />
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout}" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${c3p0.checkoutTimeout}" />

    <!-- The below property is not set because we have feeds which require 
        a lot of connections. Resetting the connectionPool size to minPoolSize might 
        not be ideal. Instead we'd use maxIdleTime and maxConnectionAge return unused 
        connections. -->
    <!-- <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections}" 
        /> -->

    <!-- The below parameters can be set to prevent connection leaks. Ideally, 
        the application should close all connections, in which case they'll be returned 
        to the pool. -->
    <!-- <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" 
        /> -->
    <!-- <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" 
        /> -->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction demarcation related invokes on the `Connection` will happen nevertheless. You could use something like Spring's `LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy` (doc'ed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html)) to avoid having these sent when they are not required.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you open a transaction and get a database connection always and only after check cache content.

But since you have opened the transactional context, it will be closed, issuing the commit, as no exceptions happened.

You most likely need to move the checking of the cache outside of the transactional context.

Of course, confirming this depends on your application code not included in the question.

Comment: I am not opening transaction manually, it is part of spring bean's DAO invocation, it happens across the application. Moreover, the caching is happening internally by hibernate using second level cache(Ehcache). Is there a possibility to check the Ehcahce before invoking any hibernate specific code. Otherwise, can we tell the hibernate not to open transaction when the data is found in cache?

Comment: Using the `LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy` I mentioned above will effectively let you do this.